# Click an element using Selenium Java based on the following html

Tags: java, selenium

The html of the element:

```
<a class="dropdown-div__button js-dropdown button" href="#" data- 
reactid=".0.0.0.3.1.0"><span class="u-pad-rs" data- 
reactid=".0.0.0.3.1.0.0">ACTIONS</span><span class="icon icon-caret-down"  
data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.1.0.1"></span></a>
```

Comment: Elaborate question with more detail, want you wants to achieve and what issue you are facing as of now

Answer (score 0):

Use this **Xpath** : `//span[text()='ACTIONS']`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='ACTIONS']")).click();
```

**cssSelector** would be :  `a[class*='js-dropdown button']`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class*='js-dropdown button']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **ACTIONS** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable and you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-div__button js-dropdown button']//span[@class='u-pad-rs']"))).click();
```